# List<T> as a property on an interface

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface

I'm trying to create an interface for a Caching class as follows:

```
public interface IDataCacheMember
{
    private List<T> _data;
    public List<T> Data;

    private void RefreshCache();
    private List<T> GetData();
}

public class StateMap : IDataCacheMember
{
    private List<States> _data;
    public List<States> Data 
    { 
        get
        {
            if (_data == null || _data.Count() < 1)
                _data = GetData();

            return _data;
        }
    }

    private void RefreshCache()
    {
        _data = GetData();
    }

    private List<States> GetData()
    {
        //API Magic to get states
    }

    private static readonly Lazy<StateMap> lazy =
        new Lazy<StateMap>(() => new StateMap());

    public static StateMap Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }

    private StateMap()
    {
        //Set a timer to call RefreshCache() every five minutes
    }
}
```

The goal is to save calls to the API on a number of small data sets for a website. These data sets don't need to be accurate up to the minute.

There is no room to use a proper caching service (Redis, etc).

The problem is I can't find a way to define a generic list for the return type of `_data` and `Data`.

What is the best way to achieve my goal? Can I have a generic return type for `_data` and `Data`, or is there another pattern I should be using that would be superior?

Comment: If you are using .NET 4.0 or newer you can use the built in [MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx) class and don't need to rely on any 3rd party caching services. You can easily set timed expirations with it's [Add methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd780614(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a generic property on an interface if you make the interface itself generic:

```
public interface IDataCacheMember<T>
{
    List<T> Data { get; }
}
```

And use it with a type parameter:

```
public class StateMap : IDataCacheMember<States>
{
    // ...
}
```

Note: **You can't have private members on an interface**. This doesn't make sense as an interface only describes an outward contract. You probably want to use an abstract class instead.

Comment: Unless he uses other cache strategies like @Scott suggested, I would definately also suggest using an abstract class, to put as much reusable code in the base class as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make the interface itself generic:

```
public interface IDataCacheMember<T>
{
    List<T> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Also, interface can't have private members.

Comment: you cannot have an access modifier in Interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not compile which always is a bad sign :)

Your cache has two important problems:

1. It isn't thread safe.
2. The values of the cache can be modified by its users.

As Scott Chamberlain suggests, please look up the `MemoryCache` class.